# OOP - predetermined breaking points and abstraction of classes

Tags: class, oop, architecture, relationship

As I like to model some real world things, I have been thinking about the problem, when classes and their relationships (association, inheritance) are getting greater and greater and you can't really split them up. The resulting problem is: How shall it fit into main memory?

Imagine: I model an **individual**, with all of it's attributes, e.g.

- Eyes
- Friends
- Pets (maybe funny, but ..)
- ...

Each of this attributes has it's own attributes, e.g.

**Pet**

- Coat
- ...

**Coat**

- Hair
- ...

**Hair**

- Color
- Length
- ...

This example is not quite clean, but that's only a rough example.

Of course there are not always linked directly, but sometimes by a collection-like special class. But what is the right way to make it not that complicated for the underlying computer (so that the application does not use too much space of the main memory) on the one hand, but make it completely on the other?

Your Steffen

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by 'not that complicated for the underlying computer'?

Comment: Hey MahlerFive, I mean that the resulting model with all its classes and relationships costs too much RAM. There are so much classes, that its bloating the application size in main memory, that it doesn't fit into the main memory anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is, **"why does this NEED to be in memory"?** In short, it doesn't. If you tried to model everything you come across in this world in the fashion you've described, you will eventually run out of memory. So then you need to store information. At that point, your memory concerns go away. RAM may be fast these days, but if you run out, it does you no good.

Comment: Hello Didaxis, thank you for your response! Well, for me the question is: where shall I make these predeterminated breaking points. Which attributes do I have to leave out? When I do so, my model library will not be complete, and that is poor. I just want to make a great library, and of course it is not possible to remove no attributes. But which attributes shall I remove and how can I plan it to be complete, maybe with glue classes or something like that? I am not a native english speaker, so maybe I behave me stupidly :D

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about fitting this into memory, it is possible to model this with SQL.

The question has, you might have several individuals, or several animals which share properties. For instance, an individual has hair as well with the same subproperties as animals. Due to this relational attribute (I'm assuming you can let both dogs and humans have brown hair for instance), you can use a SQL table with one table representing each property.

The `individual` table will have columns such as `eyes, bodyType, job` which will be foreign keys to the tables with those properties. For instance, the `job`  table holds properties such as `salary`, `position`, `company` etc.

Those work for one-to-one relationships between an individual and other things.

For many-to-one relationships, you can create tables where the individual is the parent and it is the foreign key, or tables modelling relationships themselves.

The `friends` table might have relationships such as `individual1`, `individual2` which are foreign keys to `individual`, and a `relationship` column such as `"friends"` or `"lovers"`.

This allows you to arbitrarily create relationships in a harddisk memory store which should be fairly sufficient. Depending on your application, I believe you can do this in SQLite and run it in-memory, or implement a caching layer to represent objects themselves in something like Redis.

You create the respective domain objects in memory, such as `class Individual` and `class Job` and `class Pet`. You can use the Data Mapper pattern to retrieve and submit from your SQL table as needed, allowing you to store quite a bit of things with minimal RAM and everything else persisting on hard disk.

Note: It is also possible to use NoSQL such as MongoDB since you can express everything as a document, but for minimal data repetition (many objects will have similar, related properties) I suggest SQL as a possibility.

Comment: Hello Viktor, of course there must be a way to store all these data, and a database makes sense. I decided to use a graph database, it makes most sense and takes care of the massive kinds of relationships, that actually exist :)

Comment: Which particular database are you using?

Comment: Hey, well I haven't decided it yet, but I tend to use Neo4j or OrientDB. What do you think?

Comment: I haven't really used them myself, so that's why I didn't put it in my answer. I was just interesting, thanks!